# Xcode upgrade from 5 to 6 - distorted storyboard views

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, xcode5

I recently updated my development environment from XCode v5.1 to XCode v6.1 and found a lot of elements in the new storyboard in individual "screens" as out of place. I have added two screenshots of the storyboard for the comparison

XCode 5

[image]

XCode 6

[image]

My question would be, what is the easiest way I can ensure that the elements are ordered correctly?

I did look into adaptive layouts, but using size classes only complicated things. Additionaly, the intended support is only for iPhones in a specific orientation, so don't feel the effort is necessary.

Any Ideas?

Comment: these views are automatically `SizeClass`'d by Xcode, change the size class to compact width and you will be good to go

Comment: I haven't checked on the "Use Size Classes" checkbox. Will this be still true?